# What exactly is dimension?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

In class 11th, I studied in first chapter of physics (that is unit and measurement) that dimension is an expression of a physical quantity in terms of fundamental quantity.
But immediately in second chapter (that is kinematics) I read about

**1 dimension** - body moving in straight line

**2 dimension** - body moving in x and y axis

**3 dimension** - body moving in x,y and z axis

As I am confused after reading dimension definition in first chapter and it's type (1 dimension, 2 dimension, 3 dimension) in 2nd chapter. I couldn't relate definition of dimension with its types

Hence my doubt is what exactly is dimension?

Comment: cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis

Comment: These are two different uses of the same word. Call them "dimensions of measurement" and "spacial dimensions".

Comment: Please explain dmckee

Comment: A "nail" can be something you drive with a hammer or something on the end of a finger (which you hope *not* to drive with a hammer!). One word with two distinct meanings. Same thing here. Those definitions *don't* match up because there are different definitions.

Comment: Can you give one more example like that so that I can easily get what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first chapter they are referring to an object's dimensions as it's measured size, it's length, width, or height are its dimensions.
 In the second chapter they are referring to spatial dimensions. One dimension could be represented by drawing a straight line on a flat piece of paper, it would only have length. Two dimensions could be represented by the flat piece of paper itself, it has length and width, but no height. three dimensions could be represented by a box or cube, it has length, width, and height, all three spatial dimensions.